# Edit Operation Validation for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The following codes works. But the problem is when I click the edit link to edit a product the all the text boxes gets cleared but error message are working. This is happening because Strongly Typed View class is selected which contains error message with regex. That class is being used for Create operation as well. The thing is that I want to include the errors message if a text(es) is remained empty or invalid data is enter and user tries to save in those conditions. How do can this be achieved, if possible. I am using VS 2010, MVC C#, ADO.NET.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection, 
                         ProductCategory editCategory)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            return View(editCategory);
    }

    var categoryToUpdate = db.ProductCategories.First(m => 
    m.ProductCategoryID == id);
    ViewData.Model = categoryToUpdate;
    TryUpdateModel(categoryToUpdate, new string[] { }, 
    collection.ToValueProvider());
    db.AddToProductCategories(editCategory);
    db.SaveChanges(); 
    return View("/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your model back.

If your view is named Edit you just need to:

```
return View(editCategory);
```

Comment: hi, yes that is what its doing. Image  there are two text boxes in the edit form. One for category name and the date. If I remove the string from the  textbox for the category name and leave it empty. Then remove the date from the other textbox. If I try to save the details, I get an error message for the date textbox saying it needs to fill in but no error message shown for the other box. Am I making any sense?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I coded error syntax in edit operation and it is working.